# Azure Devops API get all projects, teams and members with powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm creating a powershell script that connects to the Azure Devops API service to get all the projects, teams and team members. However I'm having some issues with the pagination of the teams, since the API only returns 1000 results. I'm usig the top and skip parameters of the query to sort this out however this is not working on my script, here's what I have:

```
$Members = @()

$Organization = 'org'
$PAT = 'pat'

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)")) }
$UriOrganization = "https://dev.azure.com/$($Organization)/"

$top_param=1000
$skip_param=0


$uriProject = $UriOrganization + "_apis/projects"
$ProjectsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriProject -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader

Foreach ($project in $ProjectsResult.value)
{
    do
    {
        $uriTeams = $UriOrganization + "_apis/projects/$($project.id)/teams?$top=$($top_param)&$skip=$($skip_param)"
        $TeamsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriTeams -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
        Foreach ($team in $TeamsResult.value)
        {
            $uriTeamMembers = $UriOrganization + "_apis/projects/$($project.id)/teams/$($team.id)/members?$top=$($top_param)&$skip=$($skip_param)"
            $TeamMembersResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriTeamMembers -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
            Foreach ($teamMember in $TeamMembersResult.value)
            {
                $Members += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    ProjectID=$project.id
                    ProjectName=$project.name
                    TeamID=$team.id
                    TeamName=$team.name
                    TeamDescription=$team.description
                    MemberID=$teamMember.identity.id
                    MemberName=$teamMember.identity.displayName
                    MemberEmail=$teamMember.identity.uniqueName
                }
            }
        }
        $Members | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File -FilePath "filepath\file.csv" -Append

        $top_param=$top_param+1000
        $skip_param=$skip_param+1000
    }
    while (1000 -lt $TeamsResult.count)
    
}
```

The issue is that my script is returning me the same results over and over again, pagination is not working.
I'm using the following documentation:

Projects Api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Teams Api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get-all-teams?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Members Api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get-team-members-with-extended-properties?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Check this PowerShell module https://github.com/MethodsAndPractices/vsteam

```
Set-VSTeamAccount -Account <account> -PersonalAccessToken <PAT>
        Get-VSTeamProject | % {
            Set-VSTeamDefaultProject -Project $_
            $_.name
            Get-VSTeam | % {
                Get-VSTeamMember -teamId $_.id
            }
        }
```